# KMZ exported from google maps is not showing some placemarks

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth, kmz

We have this map:
https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=z3MgxTVp8WWA.kbMeY2NPElcE

It can be exported into KMZ, by clicking "Download KML":
[image]

But when I try to embed this map on my own Google Maps, or even open in Google Earth, some placemarks are not displayed:

[image]

It there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I see that problem with the [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer) renderer for the Google Maps Javascript API v3:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/pps9c97a/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: "http://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?&mid=1JwCy1i6rn9ailO2MPxPj-XxX0EY&lid=z3MgxTVp8WWA.kUnMLigc_WOw",
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'status_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = kmlLayer.getStatus();
  })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="status"></div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Seems like an issue in Google's KML renderer.  If I download your KML and render it with the third party library [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) (disclaimer, I currently maintain that library), it displays OK.

[redered with geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/LT_rinkimu_apygardos_2016.kml) (but there is a performance hit due to the native rendering/lack of tile based rendering).

Note that I couldn't use the KMZ file directly, there seem to be character encoding issues with the zipped KML when rendered by geoxml3.